# C++ - Cannot compile OpenCV program

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I already searched for solutions, but cannot find any. This is still new to me, so pardon me if it is trivial. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 by the way.

I have installed OpenCV 3 binded with Python using [pyimagesearch](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu) tutorial. One of the most completed install tutorial for OpenCV I have ever encountered. So, after using Python with OpenCV for quite some time, I need to step up my game by using OpenCV with C++. 
I have copied and pasted the code for loading and displaying image for C++ from this [site](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html). Then, I compiled my program with this command:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` test.cpp -o opencv
```

At first, I got this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lippicv
```

After found the solution (by removing the `-lippicv` from `opencv.pc`), I got this output:

```
/tmp/ccriaGtQ.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String    const&, int)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1a5): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/tmp/ccriaGtQ.o: In function `cv::String::String(char const*)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringC2EPKc[_ZN2cv6StringC5EPKc]+0x4d): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
/tmp/ccriaGtQ.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0x14): undefined  reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
/tmp/ccriaGtQ.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x39): undefined  reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/ccriaGtQ.o: In function `cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_[_ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_]+0x115): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
/tmp/ccriaGtQ.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x4b):    undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is driving me crazy. I am a still a beginner for this kind of things. So, any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: can you try `g++ test.cpp -o opencv \`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv\` `

Comment: @ManthanTilva How silly of me. Thanks! It works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ManthanTilva's comment is a correct answer:

> Try g++ test.cpp -o opencv `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`